# My decipher call is returning an invalid response when trying to implement Ceasar cipher, why?

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher

function`movingShift()` performs a variation of the Caesar shift. The shift increases by 1 for each character (including spaces character).

Function `demovingShift()` should decipher returned string backwards.
I can't figure out the algorithm to decipher the returned string.

My code works only for the first few words. Then as "shift" variable grows negative the logic breaks.

```js
let u = "I should have known that you would have a perfect answer for me!!!";


function movingShift(s, shift) {
 let arr = [];

 s.split("").forEach((x, idx) => {
  let source = x.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
  if (source < 65 || source > 90) {
   arr.push(x);
   shift++;
   return;
  }
  let index = (source - 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(index);
  x === x.toLowerCase() ? arr.push(letter.toLowerCase()) : arr.push(letter);
  shift++;
 })

 let cipher = arr.join("");
 return cipher;
}

let v = movingShift(u, 1);

function demovingShift(v, shift) {
 shift = -1;
 let arr = [];
 v.split("").forEach((x, idx) => {
  let source = x.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
  if (source < 65 || source > 90) {
   arr.push(x);
   shift--;
   return;
  }
  let index = (source - 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(index);
  x === x.toLowerCase() ? arr.push(letter.toLowerCase()) : arr.push(letter);
  shift--;
 })
 return arr.join("");
}

console.log(movingShift(u, 1));
console.log(demovingShift(v, 1));
```

Returned string from the first function :

```
J vltasl rlhr zdfog odxr ypw atasl rlhr p gwkzzyq zntyhv lvz wp!!!
```

Returned string from decipher function:

```
I sho;ld ha<e k45=4 :.a: ?5; =5;2* .a<+ a 6+8,+): a49=+8 ,58 3+!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1) First inside `demovingShift` you need to change `shift = -1` to `shift = -1 * shift;`.

2) Change `let index = (source - 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;` to `let index = (source - 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;` because now `shift` is negative its possible that `(source - 65 + (shift))` value may became negative which will give incorrect character. So we can use `(source + 65 + (shift))`.

You can test it below.

```js
let u = "I should have known that you would have a perfect answer for me!!!";

function movingShift(s, shift) {
  let arr = [];

  s.split("").forEach((x, idx) => {
    let source = x.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    if (source < 65 || source > 90) {
      arr.push(x);
      shift++;
      return;
    }
    let index = (source - 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;
    let letter = String.fromCharCode(index);
    x === x.toLowerCase() ? arr.push(letter.toLowerCase()) : arr.push(letter);
    shift++;
  })

  let cipher = arr.join("");
  return cipher;
}

function demovingShift(v, shift) {
  shift = -1 * shift;
  let arr = [];
  v.split("").forEach((x, idx) => {
    let source = x.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    if (source < 65 || source > 90) {
      arr.push(x);
      shift--;
      return;
    }
    let index = (source + 65 + (shift)) % 26 + 65;
    let letter = String.fromCharCode(index);
    x === x.toLowerCase() ? arr.push(letter.toLowerCase()) : arr.push(letter);
    shift--;
  })
  return arr.join("");
}

let v = movingShift(u, 1);
console.log(u);
console.log(v);
console.log(demovingShift(v, 1));
```